# Toggle Disabled to Unable Text Fields in Sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

I am working on a new concept to allow Users to made update their account profile without the need to reload the screen to allow for updates.
Currently, I have two sections that will display the information they already submitted. By default, all field are disabled.  Each section contain an "Edit" button to allow for modifications.
The problem that I am facing is that my "Edit" buttons are enabling editing on all sections, not their own section.

[Toggle Disabled fields for editing in Sections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBUKH.png)

**Here's the HTML code:**

```
<div class="container">
<p>User should use the "Edit" button to correct any information separated in the form sections, individually.

User should be allowed to submit individual sections with updated information.</p>
<br />
<form name="ReviewInformation" method="post" class="clearfix">
        <section id="NameConfirmation" style="background-color: #F1F3F2; border-radius: 8px; clear: both;" class="border-gray">
            <!-- FIRST AND NAME SECTION -->
            <div class="col-lg-12 no-padding no-margin clearfix">
                <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11 no-padding no-margin">
                    <h1 class="h1-header"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> First &amp; Last Name Section</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 no-padding no-margin">
                    <div class="positioning">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="Edit" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 spacer"></div>
                <div class="col-mg-12 horizontal-line"></div>
                <div class="col-md-12 spacer"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" id="UserEmail" name="UserEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" disabled />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="spacer"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" id="UserPhone" name="UserPhone" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" disabled />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="spacer"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <!-- /FIRST AND LAST NAME SECTION/ -->
        </section>

        <div class="col-lg-12 spacer"></div>
        <hr class="horizontal-line" />
        <div class="spacer"></div>

        <section id="EmailPhoneConfirmation" style="background-color: #E5F2F5; border-radius: 8px; clear: both;" class="border-gray">
            <!-- EMAIL AND PHONE SECTION -->
            <div class="col-lg-12 no-padding no-margin clearfix">
                <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11 no-padding no-margin">
                    <h1 class="h1-header"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Email &amp; Phone# Section</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 no-padding no-margin">
                    <div class="positioning">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="Edit" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 spacer"></div>
                <div class="col-mg-12 horizontal-line"></div>
                <div class="col-md-12 spacer"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="emailaccount@isp.com" disabled />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="spacer"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="801-999-9999" disabled />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="spacer"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <!-- EMAIL AND PHONE SECTION -->
        </section>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <hr />
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="align-text-center">
        <button type="sumbit" id="myForm" class="btn btn-success">Submit Form</button>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here's the JS:

```
<script>
(function($) {
    $.fn.toggleDisabled = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.attr('disabled')) $this.removeAttr('disabled');
            else $this.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
    //$('input:editlink').click(function() {
    $('input:button').click(function() {
        $('input:text').toggleDisabled();
    });
});
</script>
```

Here's the **DEMO**: https://jsfiddle.net/UXEngineer/7tft16pt/35/

So, I am trying to get individual editing enable only the section they are associated with.

Can anyone help with this issue? I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$(function() {

    $('input:button').click(function() {

        $(this).closest('.col-lg-12').next().find('input:text').toggleDisabled();
    });
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/7tft16pt/38/

Use closest() -> https://api.jquery.com/closest/ , and next() -> https://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: That was AWESOME!  Thanks.